# How to get the correct location of a Scene after it has been replaced in the Stage?

Tags: java, linux, javafx-2

I know this is normally not necessary, but for my testing framework, I need to be able to replace the Scene used by my Stage (this is necessary because I don't want to just fork a new JVM for every single test and obviously, we can't restart a JavaFX Application, at least not in JavaFX 2).

However, this breaks my tests because after doing this, the Scene starts reporting an incorrect location (so I cannot find my Nodes absolute position on the screen).

Here's complete code reproducing the problem. I believe this is a bug in JavaFX, but I would like to know if anyone can see any problem first or help me with a workaround:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class BugWithScene {
static CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch( 1 );

public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
    new Thread( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Application.launch( MyApp.class );
        }
    } ).start();

    latch.await();
    // sleep a little so we can see the Scene changing
    Thread.sleep( 500 );

    Platform.runLater( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            printSceneLocation();
            // here we replace the Scene - and now the Scene location becomes 0,0
            MyApp.stage.setScene( createColorfulScene( Color.BLUE ) );
            printSceneLocation();
        }
    } );

}

public static void printSceneLocation() {
    System.out.println( new Point2D( MyApp.stage.getScene().getX(), MyApp.stage.getScene().getY() ) );
}

public static Scene createColorfulScene( Color color ) {
    VBox root = new VBox();
    root.setSpacing( 0 );
    root.getChildren().setAll( new Rectangle( 40, 50, color ) );
    return new Scene( root, 50, 60 );
}

public static class MyApp extends Application {
    static Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void start( Stage stage ) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene( createColorfulScene( Color.RED ) );
        stage.show();
        MyApp.stage = stage;
        latch.countDown();
    }
}

}
```

Running this code prints the following:

```
Point2D [x = 3.0, y = 24.0]
Point2D [x = 0.0, y = 0.0]
```

I expected the second Point should be the same as the first. The first is correct (moving the mouse to the Window's absolute coordinate shifted by this amount, you get to the expected place), the second is wrong.

This may be Linux specific, not sure... tried in Linux Mint 15, with Java 1.7.0_45-b18

Comment: Hiding, the showing the Window again, solves the problem, but is an extremely brute-force solution I want to avoid using.

Comment: I think it's specific to your OS.  I ran your app on windows 7 with Java7u45 and Java8b115 and all reported point values had the same x and y co-ordinates.

Comment: Thanks. I also confirmed this does not affect Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [know bug](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-19352) in JavaFX for Linux. It's fixed in not yet released updates to JavaFX 2 (see the *Fix Version* field in the link).

Except for the workaround that you mentioned, an alternative solution could be to replace the root node of the scene instead. I know this works for this very purpose (at least on Windows).

Comment: Thank you. I was replacing the root before, but I need to replace the whole scene to be able to re-launch one or more applications, which create their own Scene, so replacing the root is not a complete solution.

Comment: The RT-19352 bug referenced by minisu was fixed 18 months ago and I think it would have been included in a released JavaFX version by now, but perhaps minisu is correct and it has not been included yet (I left a comment on the issue in the issue tracker requesting clarification, you can [check the issue for responses](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-19352) to get a definitive answer).  Regardless, I'm not sure Renato is experiencing the exact same issue, so it is probably still worthwhile for Renato to file a new issue in the bug tracker.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have double checked that this problem does not happen in Windows 7. I agree with you my issue does not seem to be the same as RT-19352. The scene is updated correctly, just its location is reported incorrectly. I will file a bug.

Comment: Created a new issue in the JavaFX's JIRA: RT-34307, https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-34307